# How schedule sql query by Python?

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks

I have sql query and I want to run automatically daily at 9:30 am. I don't have permission to use SQL Server Agent so I try to workaround and use Python.

SQLQuery1.sql looks like:

```
with tab1 as (select....),
tab2 as (select ...)

select ...
into newtab
from tab1
left join tab2...
```

In Python works:

```
import pyodbc

con = pyodbc.connect(driver=...)
cur = con.cursor()
sql_file = open("SQLQuery1.sql")
sql_as_string = sql_file.read()
res = cur.execute(sql_as_string)
#con.commit()
print("Success!")
```

I find some information about schedule: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/
but I don't know what I should write after def job() and where I should save this code:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    #?????

schedule.every().day.at("09:30").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: For something like this to work, the scripts needs to essentially always run in the background - why not use the scheduling of your OS to kick off a script? Like the Task Scheduler in Windows, or `cron` or something like that on Linux?

Comment: if you got linux server then go for `cron` its pretty easy to set up scheduled jobs in it.

Comment: I got Windows, so I can use Task Scheduler and schedule this short python script there?